# How to check if FileObject is folder?

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using Apache Commons VFS (Virtual File System) to access some files over SFTP. Does anybody know how to check if an instance of org.apache.commons.vfs.FileContent is folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean checking `FileObject`, then you can use [`FileObject.getType()`](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs/FileObject.html#getType().  Given a non-empty `FileContent`,  you would always assume it's coming from a file.  As the specification [here](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs/FileObject.html) says:

> There are two types of files: Folders, which contain other files, and normal files, which contain data, or content. A folder may not have any content, and a normal file cannot contain other files.

Comment: fileObject.getType() == FileType.FOLDER